# imp.find_module: what constitures a module in windows and can it load a dll?

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to run a python module that is running ok in linux, but in windows it outputs

> ImportError: No module named '_foodeviceapi'

Checking the code, it fails while trying to do

```
            fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_foodeviceapi', [dirname(__file__)])
```

Checking the directory it searches I find '_foodeviceapi.so' and other .so files, which I suppose are for linux, but no respective ones for windows... I have found from the Matlab implementation the respective foodeviceapi.dll

However, when I try to use imp.find_module, I cannot seem to find the dll... Is this because I need a static library? Or am i doing something else wrong? Is it possible to load a dll? What would be the correct extension for a file imp.find_module would find in windows? The documentation does not seem to mention.

After this command, the python module in discussion goes approximately:

```
    if fp is not None:
        try:
            _mod = imp.load_module('_foodeviceapi', fp, pathname, description)
        finally:
            fp.close()
```

and defines classes like:

```
class SwigPyIterator(_object):
    ...
    def __next__(self) -> "PyObject *" : return _mod.SwigPyIterator___next__(self)
    ...
```

etc. (Its a big chunk of code, just showing some examples)

Comment: In general, "module" for `imp` functions refers to the same kind of module that you could import with `import blah`.  In general you won't be able to directly import a DLL from Python; usually there would be a Python C-extension module that somehow wraps the DLL.  I think you'll need to give more details about what it is you're trying to import, how you installed it, etc.

Comment: Its a proprietary sensor driver that we got. What you write makes sense to me, except for the fact that the code works in linux, and it does load a .so file... So somehow, they are using it to import a .so library...

Comment: I don't know enough about this stuff to know why that might be.  But basically it doesn't surprise me that dropping a DLL into a folder is not enough to make the library work on Windows even if it already seems to be working on Linux.

Comment: Checking the source code of imp.py, it only looks for directories containing '_ _ init _ _ .py' , or ' _ _ init _ _ .pyc' (which are python modules). It would be interesting if in my case the ' _ _ init _ _ .pyc' does not correspond to any (provided to me) .py ... I ll need to investigate further ...